# PHP echo -> string as 0?

Tags: php, preg-match, echo

how would I avoid that the following :

```
$_SESSION['myVar']=preg_match("[^a-zA-Z]",'',$_SESSION['myVar']);

echo $_SESSION['myVar'];
```

displays

```
0
```

and instead it displays/outputs the var content ? **preg_match** gives out **mixed** type, but this shouldnt be the problem...

Why, is the value of the string itself not addressable with echo (by **comapring** its contents, it is **OK**)?

Formerly I had

```
$_SESSION['myVar']=ereg_replace("[^a-zA-Z]",'',$_SESSION['myVar']);
```

ant the output óf **ereg_replace** was correctly displayed the variable content.

Comment: `ereg_replace()` is deprecated.

Comment: preg_replace is the answer ... somehow my blindness forced me to read preg_match as preg_replace ...  Thanks to everyone !

Comment: I just found out, it is only one possible to set one answer as the right one, although in this case there are three right answers... I just set the answer with the most up votes, although I liked all of them... There will be always someone offended, so once again thanks a lot to everyone !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PCRE in PHP need [delimiters *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) and you probably want [`preg_replace` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z]/",'',$_SESSION['myVar']);
```

Assuming you had `preg_replace`, even then, the brackets (`[...]`) would be interpreted as delimiters and so the engine would literally try to match `a-zA-Z` at the beginning of the string and would not interpret the constructor as character class.

Answer (score 1):

`preg_match` returns an int, not mixed: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Use the matches parameter to get your matches.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that preg_match returns a Boolean, 1 if the pattern was matched, 0 if it didn't. preg_match simply matches occurrences, it doesn't replace them. Here's how you use preg_match:

```
$matched = array();
preg_match("/[^a-zA-Z]/", $_SESSION["myVar"], $matches);

print_r($matches); // All matches are in the array.
```